# In dataframe, how to sum values as element wise for a large number of entries?

Tags: r

my_data contains 1920 entries: from X1.V1 to X192.V10 as below:

> pic<-my_data

```
X1.V1 X1.V2 X1.V3 X1.V4 X1.V5 X1.V6 X1.V7 X1.V8 X1.V9 X1.V10
X2.V1 X2.V2 X2.V3 X2.V4 X2.V5 X2.V6 X2.V7 X2.V8 X2.V9 X2.V10
------------------------------------------------------------
X192.V1 X192.V2 X192.V3 X192.V4 X192.V5 X192.V6 X192.V7 X192.V8 X192.V9 X192.V10
```

In this data, each entry contains 301 elements, e.g.,

> pic$X1.V1

```
  [1] -29.935  -7.798 -20.366   1.772 -10.796 -23.363
  [7]  -1.226 -13.794 -26.361  -4.224 -16.791 -29.359
 [13]  -7.222 -19.789   2.348 -10.219 -22.787  -0.650
 [19] -13.217 -25.785  -3.647 -16.215 -28.782  -6.645
 [25] -19.213   2.925  -9.643 -22.210  -0.073 -12.641
 [31] -25.208  -3.071 -15.638 -28.206  -6.069 -18.636
 [37]   3.501  -9.066 -21.634   0.503 -12.064 -24.632
 [43]  -2.494 -15.062 -27.630  -5.492 -18.060   4.078
 [49]  -8.490 -21.058   1.080 -11.488 -24.055  -1.918
 [55] -14.485 -27.053  -4.916 -17.483   4.654  -7.913
 [61] -20.481   1.656 -10.911 -23.479  -1.341 -13.909
 [67] -26.477  -4.339 -16.907 -29.474  -7.337 -19.905
 [73]   2.233 -10.335 -22.902  -0.765 -13.333 -25.900
 [79]  -3.763 -16.330 -28.898  -6.760 -19.328   2.809
 [85]  -9.758 -22.326  -0.188 -12.756 -25.324  -3.186
 [91] -15.754 -28.321  -6.184 -18.752   3.386  -9.182
 [97] -21.749   0.388 -12.180 -24.747  -2.610 -15.177
[103] -27.745  -5.608 -18.175   3.962  -8.605 -21.173
[109]   0.964 -11.603 -24.171  -2.033 -14.601 -27.168
[115]  -5.031 -17.599   4.539  -8.029 -20.596   1.541
[121] -11.027 -23.594  -1.457 -14.024 -26.592  -4.455
[127] -17.022 -29.590  -7.452 -20.020   2.117 -10.450
[133] -23.018  -0.880 -13.448 -26.015  -3.878 -16.446
[139] -29.013  -6.876 -19.443   2.694  -9.874 -22.441
[145]  -0.304 -12.871 -25.439  -3.302 -15.869 -28.437
[151]  -6.299 -18.867   3.270  -9.297 -21.865   0.273
[157] -12.295 -24.862  -2.725 -15.293 -27.860  -5.723
[163] -18.290   3.847  -8.721 -21.288   0.849 -11.718
[169] -24.286  -2.149 -14.716 -27.284  -5.146 -17.714
[175]   4.423  -8.144 -20.712   1.426 -11.142 -23.709
[181]  -1.572 -14.140 -26.707  -4.570 -17.137 -29.705
[187]  -7.568 -20.135   2.002 -10.565 -23.133  -0.996
[193] -13.563 -26.131  -3.993 -16.561 -29.128  -6.991
[199] -19.559   2.579  -9.989 -22.556  -0.419 -12.987
[205] -25.554  -3.417 -15.984 -28.552  -6.415 -18.982
[211]   3.155  -9.412 -21.980   0.157 -12.410 -24.978
[217]  -2.840 -15.408 -27.975  -5.838 -18.406   3.732
[223]  -8.836 -21.403   0.734 -11.834 -24.401  -2.264
[229] -14.831 -27.399  -5.262 -17.829   4.308  -8.259
[235] -20.827   1.310 -11.257 -23.825  -1.687 -14.255
[241] -26.822  -4.685 -17.253 -29.820  -7.683 -20.250
[247]   1.887 -10.681 -23.248  -1.111 -13.678 -26.246
[253]  -4.109 -16.676 -29.244  -7.106 -19.674   2.463
[259] -10.104 -22.672  -0.534 -13.102 -25.669  -3.532
[265] -16.100 -28.667  -6.530 -19.097   3.040  -9.528
[271] -22.095   0.042 -12.525 -25.093  -2.956 -15.523
[277] -28.091  -5.953 -18.521   3.616  -8.951 -21.519
[283]   0.619 -11.949 -24.516  -2.379 -14.947 -27.514
[289]  -5.377 -17.944   4.193  -8.375 -20.942   1.195
[295] -11.372 -23.940  -1.803 -14.370 -26.938  -4.800
[301] -17.368
```

Suppose, if I want to sum 3 entries e.g.,1st element of pic$X1.V1 + 1st element of pic$X2.V1+1st element of pic$X3.V1 and so on, it works fine by

> pic$X1.V1 + pic$X2.V1 +pic$X3.V1

However, when I want to sum from pic$X1.V1 to pic$X192.V1 using the above way. It is tedious by typing each one as below

> pic$X1.V1 + pic$X2.V1 +pic$X3.V1 +.............+ pic$X192.V1

I have tried the alternative way like below. But it does not work.

> sum(pic$X1.V1:pic$X192.V1)

```
[1] -435.505
Warning messages:
1: In pic$X1.V1:pic$X192.V1 :
  numerical expression has 301 elements: only the first used
2: In pic$X1.V1:pic$X192.V1 :
  numerical expression has 301 elements: only the first used
```

Please let me know a better method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `rowSums` function. It's optimized in C code so any other solution is probably less efficient. In this case it appears that you want the entire data.frame processed.

```
rowSums(pic)
```

If you wanted to choose only those columns that matched the pattern `Vnnn.Xmm` you could do this:

```
rowSums(pic[grepl( "^V\\d{1,3}\\.X\\d{1,2}", colnames(pic) )] )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer@42-. But it is not what I want. Each entry (e.g., pic$X1.V1 or pic$X3.V1) contains 301 elements. So, after sum the output result will be 301 elements. pic$X1.V1 + pic$X2.V1 +pic$X192.V1 = Result (301 elements). It will be like, [1st element of pic$X1.V1 + 1st element of pic$X2.V1+1st element of pic$X3.V1] and so on up to the ['301' element of pic$X1.V1 + '301' element of pic$X2.V1+'301' element of pic$X3.V1]

Comment: My answer should produce a vector with 301 elements. Each element would be the row-wise sums. But perhaps you wanted 10 such vectors?

Comment: Actually I need all X values(1 to 192) for fixed V, e.g. V2. I have modified your second code and somehow I have figured out. For pic$X1.V2 + pic$X2.V2 +pic$X3.V2 +.............+ pic$X192.V2 case, if I use it as pic[grepl( "^X\\d{1,3}.V2", colnames(pic) )]. This code works good for it. However, for V1 case, the code, pic[grepl( "^X\\d{1,3}.V1", colnames(pic) )] extracts all the V1 and V10 for X1 to X192 instead of only V1. Is there any way to solve the V1 case?

Comment: The period(.) in your pattern is a regex wild card. If you wanted it to match only “.” you could use either a “\\.”OR “[.]”